# How can I set up custom namespaces in layout file in Android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, namespaces, android-studio

I am using the dragsortlistview library for my project which requires the usage of a custom namespace in the XML file in order to customize it.

mylayout.xml:

```
<com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:divider="@color/light_grey"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    dslv:collapsed_height="2dp"
    dslv:drag_enabled="true"
    dslv:drag_handle_id="@drawable/drag_handle"
    dslv:drag_scroll_start="0.33"
    dslv:drag_start_mode="onMove"
    dslv:float_alpha="0.6"
    dslv:max_drag_scroll_speed="0.5"
    dslv:remove_enabled="true"
    dslv:remove_mode="flingRemove"
    dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.3"
    dslv:sort_enabled="true"
    dslv:track_drag_sort="false"
    dslv:use_default_controller="true"
    />
```

When I make this project I get errors like this for every attribute in the `dslv` namespace:

```
Gradle: No resource identifier found for attribute 'collapsed_height' in package 'net.mypackage'
```

How can I use custom namespace in Android Studio?

Comment: +1 bcz facing same problem

Comment: Where is the library coming from?

Comment: Any way you or @stackoverflow can post your `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 12):

`res-auto` uses the current package name, not the library package name. In your case, it translates to `net.mypackage`.

If you want to use the namespace for a library, you need to use its package name. Judging from the class name, you are using the DSLV library [from here](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview). So, you'll want to use:

```
xmlns:dslv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mobeta.android.dslv"
```

Comment: When I do this Android Studio pops up an error and tell me to use res-auto. But res-auto can't build :/

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using it in the library