# How to make this( xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" ) name space dynamic in library?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've converted my existing project as a module because I want to use it in other projects. But, when I am importing this module/library in other projects there are errors in XML files as following error log

[image]

So, I guess there is an error because of namespace differences in XML files of library and project importing the library.
I searched for this issue but didn't get a proper answer. So, is there a way to make namespace of library XML files dynamic?
`C:\Users\admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\app-release.aar\5c807d57c410bc1f5ff17c83e7fdffd7\res\layout\activity_dashboard_drawer.xml`

> Error:error: attribute 'atritechnocrat.com.cuckoomoduledemo:headerLayout' not found.
>   Error:error: attribute 'atritechnocrat.com.cuckoomoduledemo:menu' not found.

Comment: Have you check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17861530/4295522

Comment: Please include the error log directly in the question, rather than using an image.

Comment: I have added error log

Comment: @PrafullaMalviya Thank you.But we tried it.tThat is not proper way for our project.Because there are lots of xml files.